# phpmyadmin не хочет добавлять sql файл ошибка:

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Всем привет, хочу перенести мой старый сайт сделанный на WordPress с хостинга на сервак. Файлы есть, теперь проблема только с БД от WordPress. Захожу в phpmyadmin, нажимаю "Импорт" и выбираю файл. Вот всё что могу сделать: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот, нажимаю кнопочку вперёд, и он выдаёт ошибку:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решаю посмотреть доки, перехожу по ссылке, но mysql не нашёл эту статью: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я в sql полный 0. Что прикажете делать?

Comment: Что пишут в ошибке? "База данных не выбрана". Следовательно либо надо выбрать базу данных, либо в дампе должна быть команда создания и выбора базы данных.

Comment: Я не шарю, можно как то по проще?)

Comment: О, @u_mulder, я понял. Напишите пожалуйста ответом для закрытия вопроса)

Comment: Ну раз понял, то можешь сам и написать ответ) И даже потом его принять)

Comment: @u_mulder, просто тут за такое жёстко хейтят)
Лучше ты ответь) Тебе + репутация)